# Creating a Progress bar using 2 images using JavaScript & CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically what i am trying to achieve is create a progress bar kind of affect using 2 images.
(one grey scale & one colored). Trying to put these 2 divs beside one another & then modify the x-position and width of these dynamically. But facing problem to put them beside one another. Am i going in the right approach? Any other approaches for achieving this are also welcome.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking, can you post some code?

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/3qKgU/

Comment: Did any answer below fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This will work across all browsers:

**HTML**

```
<div id="progress-container">
    <span></span>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#progress-container{
    background: grey; /* default background */
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden; /* fit to the height of span */
}
#progress-container span {
    display: block;   /* to enable width and height for this element */
    background: orange;
    height: 15px;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPffE/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="one-hundred">
     <div id="percentage">
     </div>
</div>
```

try to organize your div like this?

Comment: the one "one-hundred" use the background of gray, and the other use the colored, than use javascript to change the width of "percentage" :)